# Disable tags and numbers alone in input form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, forms, input, textarea

I have a form and I would like to disable `< > # @` and numbers alone ('test 123' should work).

For the first condition I tried

```
if ( $(this).val().match("^[^>#<@*]+$") ) { // todo }
```

But it matches everytime..

I have already checked on Stackoverflow, W3Schools etc but I don't know why I cannot apply the regex

Thank you

Comment: Numbers such as `5`? Whta does that requirement mean?

Comment: I mean if the value equals just a number (like an int) it shouldn't work.

Comment: Try `.match(/^(?!\d+$)[^>#<@*]+$/)`. I'd rather use it with a `RegExp#test` method though. `/^(?!\d+$)[^>#<@*]+$/.test(s)`.

Comment: See my answer below. I added with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a negative lookbehind to the pattern you used and define the regex like

```
/^(?!\d+$)[^>#<@*]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjnkAL/1) (note `\n` is added since the demo input string contains line breaks).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` - the input string cannot consist of only 1+ digits
- `[^>#<@*]+` - 1 or more chars other than `>`, `#`, `<`, `@`, `*`
- `$` - end of string.

Use it with a `RegExp#test` to only return `true` or `false` (with `String#match`, there is unnecessary overhead related to returning all the array with values that you do not need here):

```
if (/^(?!\d+$)[^>#<@*]+$/.test($(this).val())) {....}
```

Comment: Works too thank you !! , I give you the green check because you explained me better than other answers

Comment: @XavierC.: Actually, it is the answer that works as per your original requirements. Gawil's answer will fail  if there are non-digits on the second line, not the first one, and Bhushan's solution just matches any string that contains 1+ alphanumeric or whitespace chars *anywhere* inside a string. If you negate the test check, you will match strings that do not contain these chars. I believe my answer is the only correct one.

Comment: Yes I understood it by seeing your RegEx, A+ dude!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to match string with at least one character that is not a digit and without the following characters : `<, >, # and @`
You can do that with this regex :
`(?=.*\D)[^<>#@]*`

Answer (score 1):

Try below: using RegExp object you can test the pattern as shown below

```
var regEx = new RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z\\s]+"); 
if ( regEx.test($(this).val()) )
```

Comment: This matches numbers